# Kafka Connect - How to delete a connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I created a cassandra-sink connector after that I made some changes in `connector.properties` file. After stopping the worker and starting it again, now when I add the connector using:

```
java -jar kafka-connect-cli-1.0.6-all.jar create cassandra-sink-orders < cassandra-sink-distributed-orders.properties
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: the Kafka Connect API returned: Connector cassandra-sink-orders already exists (409)
```

How can I remove the existing connector?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [Kafka Connect REST API](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/restapi.html#delete--connectors-(string-name)-), which includes an endpoint for `DELETE`ing a connector.

```sh
curl -X DELETE http://$KAFKACONNECTWORKER_HOST:$KAFKACONNECTWORKER_PORT/connectors/$CONNECTOR_NAME
```

For example:

```sh
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8083/connectors/src-jdbc-orders
```

See it in action here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EenWEm-5dg&t=378s

Comment: This might be intentional, but for me this was counter intuitive, when you delete a connector, and you POST a connector with the same name, it re-uses to some degree the old config. For example I had a corrupt Debezium connector with a binlog offset that no longer existed. I deleted it, then created it again, thinking it would start from scratch with the first binlog it could find, but it started at the same broken offset.

Answer (score 62):

To delete a connector, you can run:

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8083/connectors/<connector-name>
```

Comment: in my opinion this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @DanielBelémDuarte fair point. I've editing my answer to hopefully make it more useful.

Comment: And once you delete it then you can verify it is gone with `curl -s http://localhost:8083/connectors | jq`